How to unlock user data of my Huawei Honor phone without losing the data？
I have switched on my old Huawei Honor phone after a long gap. On the screen, I have a message stating below

Android system

User data locked
Password required after you restart the device
Some features are disabled automatically for security


I have given the pattern that I remember giving when I used to use it, but then it doesn't get unlocked, and it says incorrect pattern. I tried various other patterns, but they didn't work.
Can anyone help unlock my phone without losing data?

no way to decrypt without correct pattern
